# PC makes beeping sound after booting up

Tags: windows-10, boot, desktop-computer

Short history, it's a custom build PC from oversea (Windows 10), 1 year old now and it was a real hassle to recieve it. Once I had finally my PC, it was damaged, I send it back and the same hassle again. After the second time, my PC finally worked but it had a beeping sound during the boot process, sometimes, not always, my PC worked, so I did not thought much about it, now 1 year later, still there.
As mentioned, the beeping sound does not happen always, only sometimes.

Does anyone recognize it? I already checked for lose parts but couldn't find anything.

I recorded the beeping with my phone:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KCmjf_UerTF48h0YWd04Ntn6UQc16G45?usp=sharing

Edit: I found something online:

"One long and three short beeps" from speaker
An anomaly is detected in the graphic card. If the graphic card needs an extra power supply, please ensure the power supply can provide enough wattage.

The motherboard is an [Asus TUF Gaming X570-plus](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-X570-PLUS/).

But it doesn't happens always? So I have to replace the cable/ have to figure out which cable I need? This is a bit too much for my walnut brain.

Comment: Motherboards beep at boot when POST fails - review the manual for your PC/motherboard for what the number of beeps means.

Comment: It would be better to tell us how many beeps there are and give us a link to the motherboard manufacturer's page for the motherboard.

Comment: As for letting everyone access the file on Google Drive, you could put it in a folder with a name like "Public" and [Share folders in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529).

Comment: Oh no, I thought I made everything correct and still screwed up :| I hope the file works now... they did not gave me a manual... I have to look up online I guess.

Comment: [This thread on pcspecialist.co.uk](https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/threads/one-long-beep-and-three-short-ones-but-everything-works.75510/) suggests that it could be prevented by making sure the monitor is switched on before the computer.

Comment: Are you using the integrated graphics or a separate graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment since I'm a new user too. The video you linked asked for access to view it.

They most likely added a [motherboard speaker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCCFlC_tlcI) to your computer while they had it. It's used to sound out error codes when something goes wrong during the boot process. Most sound out one beep during normal boot.

You can read more about what other beeps mean in your computer's manual.